# Acceleration compensation on rotation vector using android device

Tags: android, rotation, sensors, android-sensors, acceleration

I'm triying to get the inclination of an android device mounted on a moving vehicle using TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR with sensor manager.

It works fine until the vehicle accelerates or decelerates suddenly, moment in which it becomes a bit crazy and gives wrong values.

Is there any way to compensate the acceleration or is there any way to measure the inclination using raw sensor data which has in account the device acceleration?

Comment: Did you find solution? i am also working on same applictionand and facing same issue. 
Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately there is no good solution, I finally did a routine to skip readings when there where an acceleration bigger than a limit